# SSH client not found on cygwin64?

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I startup the cygwin bash prompt using the batch script but there is no ssh command. How do I setup an SSH client in cygwin64?

Comment: It's there just not by default. You run the cygwin setup installation file and search for the package you want, in this case ssh and openssh will come up there. e.g. see pics here  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/preinstall_req_cygwin_ssh.htm#EMBSC281

Comment: and this is not even specific to cygwin64 just cygwin

Comment: and I would add that the instructions on that oracle link are needlessly complex. But as mentioned, see the pics there. it's just a question of running the installation file clicking next checking ssh clicking next and finish. Then ssh will be there

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `openssh` package (containing both the OpenSSH server and client software) is not part of Cygwin's *minimal base packages*.  The same `setup-x86_64.exe` for installing and updating Cygwin itself is used for installing individual packages such as `openssh`.

Answer (score 13):

Click on the `setup-x86_64.exe` and then click next till you reach to the Select packages menu.

In the search do the following:

1. Type `openssh` in the search box
2. It will search for openssh > click on Net package > click on skip > check the two boxes that pop up.
3. Click on next till you finish the install
4. Search for `cygwin` and then right click it and "Run as Administrator"
5. Type `ssh` command in the command line of cygwin
6. You will see something similar to the following:

[image]